# How to create join query for multiple models with separate conditions in laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to create join query for multiple models with separate (model) conditions.

I have create following query :

```
select * from studentinformation as s left join studentattandence a on s.id =

 a.studentid where s.PersonalFirstName='Kathi' and s.PersonalLastName='irfan' 

and s.Age='2' and s.gender ='Male' and s.StudentCourse='1' and 

s.GuardianFirstName='test' and s.GuardianLastName = 'test' and a.date 

BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2015-02-07'
```

Table of **studentinformation** model name is "**StudentAdmissionModel**".

Table of **studentattandence** model name is "**StudentAttandenceModel**".

How can i do this laravel Eloquent ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to declare a relationship between the two in the StudentAdmissionModel, which would look something like this:

```
class StudentAdmissionModel extends Eloquent {
    public function attendance()
    {
        // Assuming a one-to-one relationship
        return $this->hasOne('StudentAttandenceModel','studentid');
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to use the whereHas() function to query the relationship:

```
$admissions = StudentAdmissionModel::where('PersonalFirstName','=','Kathi')
->where('PersonalLastName','=','irfan')
->where('Age','=','2')
->where('gender','=','Male')
->where('StudentCourse','=','1')
->where('GuardianFirstName','=','test')
->where('GuardianLastName ','=','test')
->whereHas('attendance',function($q)
{
    $q->whereBetween('date', array('2015-02-01','2015-02-07'));
})
->with('attendance') // Optional eager loading, but recommended
->get();
```

And you would be able to access the fields like this:

```
foreach( $admissions as $admission){
    echo $admission->gender;
    // or
    echo $admission->attendance->date;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `->where('Age', '2')` rather than `->where('Age','=','2')`